# Transfer elements from an XML document to another using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to move elements from an XML file to another using XSLT 1.0.
The problem I have is that I know how to generate a new XML file as an output, but I cannot figure how to merge the output with an already existing file without erasing it and I couldn't find someone with the same problem.

I have the following files:

```
<list xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Matchs2.xsd">

    <!-- liste des matchs -->
    <listMatchs>
        <!-- matchs poule 1 -->
        <match>
            <date>2015-01-09</date>
            <groupe>1</groupe>
            <equipes>
                <domicile>11</domicile>
                <invite>12</invite>
            </equipes>
            <score victoire="invite">1-2</score>
        </match>
        <match>
            <date>2015-02-09</date>
            <groupe>1</groupe>
            <equipes>
                <domicile>11</domicile>
                <invite>13</invite>
            </equipes>
            <score victoire="domicile">3-2</score>
        </match>
    </listMatchs>
    <listEquipes>
        <equipe id="France" flag="/flag/fra.png">
            <position numGroupe="1" numEquipe="11"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Espagne" flag="/flag/esp.png">
            <position numGroupe="2" numEquipe="21"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Allemagne" flag="/flag/ger.png">
            <position numGroupe="3" numEquipe="31"/>
        </equipe>
            <equipe id="Angleterre" flag="/flag/eng.png">
                <position numGroupe="4" numEquipe="41"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Portugal" flag="/flag/por.png">
            <position numGroupe="5" numEquipe="51"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Belgique" flag="/flag/bel.png">
            <position numGroupe="6" numEquipe="61"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Italie" flag="/flag/ita.png">
            <position numGroupe="1" numEquipe="12"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Russie" flag="/flag/rus.png">
            <position numGroupe="2" numEquipe="22"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Republique tcheque" flag="/flag/cze.png">
            <position numGroupe="1" numEquipe="13"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Turquie" flag="/flag/tur.png">
            <position numGroupe="1" numEquipe="14"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Suede" flag="/flag/swe.png">
            <position numGroupe="2" numEquipe="23"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Republique Irlande" flag="/flag/irl.png">
            <position numGroupe="2" numEquipe="24"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Suisse" flag="/flag/sui.png">
            <position numGroupe="3" numEquipe="32"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Pologne" flag="/flag/pol.png">
            <position numGroupe="3" numEquipe="33"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Islande" flag="/flag/isl.png">
            <position numGroupe="3" numEquipe="34"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Autriche" flag="/flag/aut.png">
            <position numGroupe="4" numEquipe="42"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Roumanie" flag="/flag/rou.png">
            <position numGroupe="4" numEquipe="43"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Pays de Galles" flag="/flag/wal.png">
            <position numGroupe="4" numEquipe="44"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Croatie" flag="/flag/cro.png">
            <position numGroupe="5" numEquipe="52"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Ukraine" flag="/flag/ukr.png">
            <position numGroupe="6" numEquipe="62"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Slovaquie" flag="/flag/slo.png">
            <position numGroupe="5" numEquipe="53"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Hongrie" flag="/flag/hon.png">
            <position numGroupe="6" numEquipe="63"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Albanie" flag="/flag/alb.png">
            <position numGroupe="5" numEquipe="54"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe id="Irlande du Nord" flag="/flag/nir.png">
            <position numGroupe="6" numEquipe="64"/>
        </equipe>
    </listEquipes>
</list>
```

and:

```
<resultats xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLo``cation="Matchs_recap.xsd">


    <match date="26-01-2015">
        <equipe score="5" id="41">
            <pays>Angleterre</pays>
            <poule>4</poule>
            <drapeau src="/flag/eng.png"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe score="2" id="42">
            <pays>Autriche</pays>
            <poule>4</poule>
            <drapeau src="/flag/aut.png"/>
        </equipe>
    </match>
    <match date="26-02-2015">
        <equipe score="4" id="41">
            <pays>Angleterre</pays>
            <poule>4</poule>
            <drapeau src="/flag/eng.png"/>
        </equipe>
        <equipe score="3" id="43">
            <pays>Roumanie</pays>
            <poule>4</poule>
            <drapeau src="/flag/rou.png"/>
        </equipe>
    </match>
</resultats>
```

(it's in French, sorry for that)

I already have the XSLT to give the first file the same structure as the second, but I am looking for a way to put it into the second file. I have tried something with the document() function, but it didn't work. Is there a way to do this?
Thank you.

EDIT: Sorry for the missing elements.
Here is my expected output:

```
    <resultats xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Matchs_recap.xsd">


        <match date="26-01-2015">
            <equipe score="5" id="41">
                <pays>Angleterre</pays>
                <poule>4</poule>
                <drapeau src="/flag/eng.png"/>
            </equipe>
            <equipe score="2" id="42">
                <pays>Autriche</pays>
                <poule>4</poule>
                <drapeau src="/flag/aut.png"/>
            </equipe>
        </match>
        <match date="26-02-2015">
            <equipe score="4" id="41">
                <pays>Angleterre</pays>
                <poule>4</poule>
                <drapeau src="/flag/eng.png"/>
            </equipe>
            <equipe score="3" id="43">
                <pays>Roumanie</pays>
                <poule>4</poule>
                <drapeau src="/flag/rou.png"/>
            </equipe>
        </match>
        <match date="09-01-2015">
            <equipe score="1" id="11">
                <pays>France</pays>
                <poule>1</poule>
                <drapeau src="/flag/fra.png"/>
            </equipe>
            <equipe score="2" id="12">
                <pays>Italie</pays>
                <poule>1</poule>
                <drapeau src="/flag/ita.png"/>
            </equipe>
        </match>
        <match date="09-02-2015">
            <equipe score="3" id="11">
                <pays>France</pays>
                <poule>1</poule>
                <drapeau src="/flag/fra.png"/>
            </equipe>
            <equipe score="2" id="13">
                <pays>Republique tcheque</pays>
                <poule>1</poule>
                <drapeau src="/flag/cze.png"/>
            </equipe>
        </match>
</resultats>
```

My XSL file is the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl"
    version="1.0">


    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">    
        <resultats xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Matchs_recap.xsd">

            <xsl:for-each select="list/listMatchs/match">
                <match>
                    <xsl:attribute name="date">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(date,9,2),'-',substring(date,6,2),'-',substring(date,1,4))"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <equipe>

                        <xsl:variable name="idEquipe" select="equipes/domicile"/>
                        <xsl:attribute name="score">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(score,'-')"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$idEquipe"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>

                        <pays>
                            <xsl:value-of select="/list/listEquipes/equipe[position/@numEquipe = $idEquipe]/@id"/>
                        </pays>
                        <poule>
                            <xsl:value-of select="/list/listEquipes/equipe/position[@numEquipe = $idEquipe]/@numGroupe"/>
                        </poule>
                        <drapeau>
                            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                <xsl:value-of select="/list/listEquipes/equipe[position/@numEquipe = $idEquipe]/@flag"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </drapeau>
                    </equipe>

                    <equipe>

                        <xsl:variable name="idEquipe" select="equipes/invite"/>
                        <xsl:attribute name="score">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(score,'-')"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$idEquipe"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>

                        <pays>
                            <xsl:value-of select="/list/listEquipes/equipe[position/@numEquipe = $idEquipe]/@id"/>
                        </pays>
                        <poule>
                            <xsl:value-of select="/list/listEquipes/equipe/position[@numEquipe = $idEquipe]/@numGroupe"/>
                        </poule>
                        <drapeau>
                            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                <xsl:value-of select="/list/listEquipes/equipe[position/@numEquipe = $idEquipe]/@flag"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </drapeau>
                    </equipe>
                </match>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </resultats>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please also add the XSLT you have created. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post your XSLT **and** the expected output. Note that a XSL transformation will not modify any of the input documents; it will create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('resultats.xml')/resultats/match"/>
```

to your template, right after `</xsl:for-each>`. Replace `resultats.xml` with the path to your second XML document.